# Where statements for many to many relations hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database showing the relationship much more like this
[image]
I want to get information out of two table gmail and bloggerwith conditions blog[blogger] and user[gmail] value exists in table md_parse_blogger
 I want to know how to make a correct syntax where,please help me

```
public List showDatawebA(String blog, String url) {
        String sql = "FROM MdParse g,MdBlogger b,MdParseBlogger pb"
                + " WHERE pb.mdBlogger=:blog and pb.mdParse=:url";
        Query createQuery = currentSession.createQuery(sql);
        createQuery.setParameter("blog", blog);
        createQuery.setParameter("url", url);
        return createQuery.list();
    }
```

With mdBlogger,mdGmail is attribute class MdParseBlogger,

```
public class MdParseBlogger  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private MdParseBloggerId id;
     private MdBlogger mdBlogger;
     private MdParse mdParse;
     ...........
    }
```

ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:479)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.showDataweb(DBTable.java:76)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.main(DBTable.java:83)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Can you try property name instead of index for setParameter() like:
`createQuery.setParameter("blog", blog);   createQuery.setParameter("url", url); `

Comment: I searched under your guidance, but I just find the result using mapping.I just want to use the query,if possible I hope you can write me a code example or specific path to help me solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed named and ordinal parameters. It should be either

```
   String sql ="FROM MdGmail g,MdBlogger b,MdParseBlogger pb"
            + " WHERE pb.mdBlogger=? and pb.mdGmail=?";
    Query createQuery = currentSession.createQuery(sql);
    createQuery.setParameter(1, blog);
    createQuery.setParameter(2, url);
```

Or

```
   String sql ="FROM MdGmail g,MdBlogger b,MdParseBlogger pb"
            + " WHERE pb.mdBlogger=:blog and pb.mdGmail=:url";
    Query createQuery = currentSession.createQuery(sql);
    createQuery.setParameter("blog", blog);
    createQuery.setParameter("url", url);
```

Comment: Thank you @StanislavL command was active and forgive my greed. I hope you can help me more questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060344/hibernate-illegalargumentexception-in-class-getter-method-of-property

Comment: My english is not so good to see you delete a your comment in a new question I worry I've used the word makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: @MaTâm no, your English is fine. I just removed wrong answer ). Try to add your entities code there. Looks like something wrong with returned types (may be getters)

Comment: I'm happy with that,I luckily found the answer to the question new that is rather transmission String value that I would pass the Class Blogger and Gmail. Hope it can help you in the future with similar problems

Comment: I was a little hasty when I think I've found the solution to my problems, conditional statement inactive but there is no error message appears http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060344/conditions-for-returns-in-hibernate