# Conditions for returns in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

**My database**
[image]

I want to retrieve information of all tables with the conditions of the table dataweb url received value is "example.com" , But when I run my command, it will display all of the data instead of limiting is example.com

**CLASS DBTable**

```
public class DBTable {
    public List showDataweb(MdParse url) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    Session currentSession = sf.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "FROM MdGmail g,MdBlogger b,MdParseBlogger pb,MdParse p,MdDataweb w"
                + " WHERE w.url=:url";
        Query createQuery = currentSession.createQuery(sql);
        createQuery.setParameter("url", url);
        return createQuery.list();
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MdParse mdParse = new MdParse();
    mdParse.setUrl("example.com");
    List<Object[]> showDataweb = instance1.showDataweb(mdParse);
    for (Object[] showDataweb1 : showDataweb) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(showDataweb1));
    }
}
```

**CLASS HibernateUtil**

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your entities...

Comment: @killer This is my Hibernate mapping,if I add the question, the question will be too long so I moved them to the blog. http://sourcecode-programming.blogspot.com/2015/12/class-mdblogger-package-dbmanual.html I look forward to your help.Thank

Comment: where is the mapping file? Do you used hibernate annotation?? The link you have mentioned have only POJO classes.

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge did not understand what you asked me to provide,I have edited the questions.Looking forward to your help

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: @Thank killer but I need to display data as links to articles that table does not fit, I think my way of doing almost exactly but I still do not understand why my data when outputting improper conditions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96874/discussion-between-ma-tam-and-killer).